# Passing link and id both with href in bootstrap collapse

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm using the similar bootstrap collapse as mentioned in the code below. I want the 'Collapsible Group 1', 'Collapsible Group 2', 'Collapsible Group 3' to point to some other page with expanding the collapse part. 
In href, id of the division is mentioned it should also point to some other page.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
    href= 
    "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script 
    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
   <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
  <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
  <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h4 class="panel-title">
          <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
        </h4>
      </div>
      <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
        <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
        sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
        quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You're using BS 3, so please tag the question to the right version of Bootstrap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that with event handlers

```js
$('#collapse2').on("shown.bs.collapse", function() {

  //Here you can use window.location = "" to redirect or do something else.

  console.log("Collapse Opened");

})

//And so on for all the collapses
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Accordion Example</h2>
    <p><strong>Note:</strong> The <strong>data-parent</strong> attribute makes sure that all collapsible elements under the specified parent will be closed when one of the collapsible item is shown.</p>
    <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">Collapsible Group 2</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
          <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">Collapsible Group 3</a>
          </h4>
        </div>
        <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```